# Why is my time intelligence measure not returning any results?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, measure

Why is my time intelligence measure not returning any results?

This measure returns results:

```
Activity = 
COUNTROWS(FILTER('Inspection Data', [Inspection Type] = "Safety Activities"))
```

And so does this measure:

```
Leadership Activity MTD = 
VAR CurrentMonth = MONTH(TODAY())
RETURN 
CALCULATE('Key Measures'[Activity], MONTH('Inspection Data'[End Date]) = CurrentMonth)
```

**However, this one returns a blank:**

```
Activity YTD = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Inspection Data'),
    DATESYTD('Inspection Data'[End Date]),
    'Inspection Data'[Inspection Type] = "Safety Activities"
)
```

I am not getting error messages.

[image: This is the relationship between the fact and date dimension table]

[image: Dimension table Date column format]

[image: Fact table date column]

Comment: Note: I have now disabled Time Intelligence for current file but the result is still blank.

Comment: Is it ok to use time intelligence with COUNTROWS function? Do I still need CALCULATE? I'm wondering if this is the reason it's not working for me...

Comment: You may want to go through the “fast track” DAX link I provided in your last question to better under how to use time intelligence (as well as the use of CALCULATE). You are not using the connected date table in the measures. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It turns out it was related to the date range in the Date dim table. Is it not allowed to have dates beyond the dates in the Fact table?

Comment: The range of dates depends on your use case. It can go beyond the related date range in your fact table. It does not matter. If there is no related value/record for a chosen date (range), the result is blank.

Comment: Thanks again. If the date range in Dim table stops at the end of June the MTD measure works correctly, however if the date range goes beyond June and into July, it stops working. I must be missing something. Do I need to perform any filtering?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by not working.  But, yes, if you don’t use any slicer or visuals to filter/set the date and you want to get the MTD of the most recent/current month of your data then you can add another filter condition in your MTD measure to limit the date table range to the current month (and year; or current date)

Comment: Thank you. I've added a slicer and selected 2023.

Not only does this not return any results but the column isn't being displayed in the table:

CALCULATE ( SELECTEDMEASURE (), DATESYTD ( 'Date Dimension'[Date] ) )

But this returns correct results and displays the column in my visual:

CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDMEASURE (),
    DATESYTD (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES ( 'Date Dimension'[Date] ),
            KEEPFILTERS ( 'Date Dimension'[Date] <= TODAY () )
        )
    )
)

Why does the first column result in column not being displayed in the visual?

Comment: I think it is better to follow up with your same question/issue posted here, where @David Bacci summarized it very detailed for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399434/what-am-i-missing-for-time-intelligence-to-work … I would again encourage you to get the understanding of the fundamentals of PowerBI. It looks like you are trying to solve an assignment step by step via stackoverflow without enough understanding while trying to catch up on the fly. Good luck!