# What am I missing for time intelligence to work?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

This measure returns 5, which is correct

```
Count = COUNTROWS('Fact')
```

This measure however returns zero results

```
Count MTD = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Fact'), DATESMTD('Date'[Date]))
```

What am I missing? Do I need additional columns in my database model? Is the formatting incorrect? Why is it returning zero results?

If the date range in Dim table stops at the end of June the MTD measure works correctly, however if the date range goes beyond June and into July, it stops working. Why is this happening and what am I missing?

[image: Blank result and zero filtering]
[image: PowerBI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions going on here. Firstly, your date table should have a full calendar year for the values that exist in your fact table. In your case, you need a calendar table that goes from 01/01/2023 - 31/12/2023. Secondly, you must mark this as a date table as follows:

[image]

Now the actual logic of DATESMTD. If you write your measure and place it in a card, then the answer will be blank. This is because of the filter context. If you place your measure in a table, it will look like this:

[image]

The reason it *works* in table is because the evaluation context is being provided by each row and so you get the right result. When you place the measure in a card, the last month in context is December and so the answer is blank. If you have rows in your fact table for December then they will show in the card.

When you say DATESMTD to DAX, it needs to know the month you're talking about. If no month is supplied, it will take the last visible one which in this case is December and so correctly returns blank.

Comment: Thank you.  I will implement the changes to my date calendar as per your suggestions. I managed to get my measure to work by doing this. Is this bad practice? 

Count MTD = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Fact'),
    DATESMTD(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('Date'[Date]),
            KEEPFILTERS('Date'[Date] <= TODAY())
        )
    )
)

Comment: You don't need to do it that way. Time intelligence functions are shortcuts to avoid having to do things like that. If you provide the right filter context as I have described, then they work perfectly.

Comment: @user12804, if you want the visual to default to current month, try a page or report-level filter (relative date is in the last 1000 years or create a custom column with a boolean `[Date] < TODAY()` and use that as a page/report filter).

Comment: Apologies, @DavidBacci I cannot seem to get the filter context right. What exactly do I need to do? Create a measure to identify if date is after today and if so exclude it from the report, as per Luke_3 comment?

Comment: (Just to “merge” with your other question related to the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76398780/why-is-my-time-intelligence-measure-not-returning-any-results?noredirect=1#comment134724963_76398780) … a brief summary: usually the measure works in the context of the visuals and slicers. If you want this measure to work without (or independent to) this context and to show you the current month: one solution is to add the filter condition to your measure or, as mentioned by @Luke_0, by setting the page level filter. Good luck!

Comment: If you want the card to work up until today, you can write: Count MTD = 
CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Fact'), DATESMTD('Date'[Date])),
    'Date'[Date] = TODAY()
)

Comment: Thank you @DavidBacci
The measure you suggested:
Count MTD 3 = CALCULATE( CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Fact'), DATESMTD('Date'[Date])), 'Date'[Date] = TODAY() )
Returns the correct result in a card, but not in a table. In a table it returns the same value regardless of the month, and it also repeats the same value for all future months.
The following measure returns the correct result in both a card and table:
Count MTD = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Fact'),
    DATESMTD(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('Date'[Date]),
            KEEPFILTERS('Date'[Date] <= TODAY())

Comment: What I'm aiming for however, is to get the following measure to work in a card:
Count MTD 2 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Fact'), DATESMTD('Date'[Date]))
Creating a slicer and manually selecting dates up to and including today fixes the problem. I'd prefer not to have a slicer on the report. Is it best if I create a new column in my Date table to return false if date in fact table is a future date? Or is it better if I create a measure as per Luke's suggestion?

Comment: @DavidBacci I'm finally getting somewhere :)
I've created a custom column in my date table
ExcludeFutureDates = 'Date'[Date] <= TODAY()
And I've included this column as filter on all pages, I've set it to True.
The values now display correctly :)

Thank you so much for your patience!!!!